# С++ how do I write a function in a structure (singly linked list) that will allow me to add elements in ascending order?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to write a function in a structure that will allow me to put elements in a singly linked list in ascending order.

for example, I write in the main method:
push(27)
push(4)
push(11)

at the output I should get a list
4 11 27

now my structure looks like this

```
struct Node 
{
    int info;
    Node* next;
    Node(int value) 
    {
        info = value; 
        next = nullptr;
    }
    Node()
    {
        info = NULL;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

struct list 
{
    Node* first;
    Node* last;

    list() 
    {
        first = nullptr; 
        last = nullptr;
    }

    void push_back(int info) 
    {
        Node* lp = new Node(info);
        if (first == nullptr) 
        {
            first = lp;
            last = lp;
            return;
        }
        last->next = lp;
        last = lp;
    }
    
    void push(int info) 
    {
        //here I need to implement a method
    }

    void print() {
        if (first == nullptr) 
        {
            return;
        }
        Node* pl = first;
        while (pl) 
        { 
            cout << pl->info << " ";
            pl = pl->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

struct Node* sortedMerge(struct Node* a, struct Node* b)
{
    if (a == NULL) {
        return b;
    }

    else if (b == NULL) {
        return a;
    }

    struct Node* result = NULL;

    if (a->info <= b->info)
    {
        result = a;
        result->next = sortedMerge(a->next, b);
    }
    else {
        result = b;
        result->next = sortedMerge(a, b->next);
    }

    return result;
}


int main() 
{
    
}
```

I tried to implement it like this, but nothing works

Comment: Still the most reliable method: take pen(cil) and paper, draw lists using boxes and arrows, and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: For a background, search the internet for "C++ insert sort linked list".

Comment: Insert sort is easy.  Start at the head and traverse through the list looking for a *good* place to insert the new node.  To make insertion easier, you'll want to maintain a pointer to the previous node.

Comment: It makes me a bit sad that I almost never see linked list question tagged C++ using C++ idioms and best practices. Like a class. Nesting the Node.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion in a singly linked list requires finding the spot where you will insert, and then changing a couple pointer assignments. The trick with a singly linked list is that you need to track two nodes; the goal is to insert your new node between them. Drawing this out on paper shows this to be the only way.

If you want to keep the list sorted in ascending order, you need to be able to walk the entire list until you find a node that is equal to or greater than the value you want to insert. Your node goes before that node.

There are also different states of the list that we have to consider for insertion:

- What if the list is empty?
- What if our new value needs to be the head?
- What if our new value needs to be the tail?

Here's an example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class SList {
 public:
  SList() = default;
  SList(const SList& other);
  SList(SList&& other) noexcept;
  ~SList();

  void ascending_sort_insert(T val);

  // Employing copy-swap idiom; that's why the parameter is taken by value
  SList& operator=(SList rhs);

  friend void swap(SList<T>& lhs, SList<T>& rhs);

  // This function is for convenience and demonstration; I don't want to be
  // bothered implementing the minimal iterator required for a range-based
  // for loop.
  void print() const;

 private:
  struct Node {
    T data = T();
    Node* next = nullptr;
  };

  Node* head = nullptr;
  Node* tail = nullptr;
};

template <typename T>
void SList<T>::ascending_sort_insert(T val) {
  // Empty list
  if (!head) {
    head = new Node{.data = val};
    tail = head;
    return;
  }

  // Find our insertion spot
  Node* prev = nullptr;
  Node* curr = head;
  while (curr != nullptr && curr->data < val) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  if (prev) {
    // Middle and tail insertion
    prev->next = new Node{.data = val, .next = curr};
    if (prev == tail) {
      tail = prev->next;
    }
  } else {
    // Head insertion
    Node* tmp = new Node{.data = val, .next = head};
    head = tmp;
  }
}
```

Given this program:

```cpp
#include "slist.hpp"

int main() {
  SList<int> list;
  list.ascending_sort_insert(27);
  list.ascending_sort_insert(4);
  list.ascending_sort_insert(11);
  list.ascending_sort_insert(50);

  list.print();
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
4 11 27 50
```

I'm only including code relevant to the question being asked, so this won't compile as-is. But it does show one example of how you could do a sorted-by-ascending insert.